# How to show DataGrid row value in textbox C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing an application. where I need to show row value in the textbox. Sometimes this is working but sometimes it's not working. Please help. Here is the code which I'm using:

```
private void CRUD_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxID.Text = CRUD.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxStates.Text = CRUD.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxName.Text = CRUD.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxAddress.Text = CRUD.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxCenter.Text = CRUD.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxCity.Text = CRUD.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();


        DataRow Row = tblCRUD.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        DataRow newRow = tblCRUD.NewRow();
        newRow.ItemArray = Row.ItemArray;
        tblCRUD.Rows.Remove(Row);
        tblCRUD.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in CRUD.Rows)
        {
            CRUD.Rows[item.Index].Selected = false;
        }
        CRUD.Rows[0].Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: *but sometimes it's not working* ... elaborate more what's not working?

Comment: What is the difference between CRUD and tblCRUD? Which one works and which one doesn't work? On what conditions doesn't it work? Have you tried to step through the come and see what you get?

Comment: @SollyM one is a gridview another is a datatable

Comment: @Rahul When I run this programme, on click of some cells this is working properly & showing me the row data in textboxes & on some clicks, this is not working (not showing the selected row data).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell dataGridViewCell = null;

        if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGridView dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
            if (dataGridView != null)
                dataGridViewCell = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        }
        else
            dataGridViewCell = null;

        if (dataGridViewCell != null)
            textBox1.Text = dataGridViewCell.Value.ToString();
    }
```